# Is it possible to export Chrome custom Search Engines

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I know that it auto syncs between devices but I have 2 account and I'd like to export the custom search engines under `chrome://settings/searchEngines` and maybe import it in another account.

I know that this doesn't seem possible by default but maybe someone created a script or an extension to do it :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657472/setting-the-default-search-provider-on-chrome-via-a-script